# Expression testing with Log's?

Tags: expression-test

If $I \leq \frac{a}{b}$ then is $-\ln I \geq -\ln \frac{a}{b}$ true? Here $a,b>0$ and $I\geq 0$.

I tried:

```
w[i_] = -Log[i];

cons = {a > 0, b > 0, i <= a/b, x >= 0};

Assuming[cons, w[i] >= -Log[a/b] // Simplify]
```

Comment: `Resolve[ForAll[i, w[i] >= -Log[a/b]], Reals]` returns `False` if I understood correctly the OP and likewise `Resolve[ForAll[i, w[i] >= -Log[a/b]], PositiveReals]`

Comment: @bmf Can you find an instance where it is false?

Comment: @bmf, Tying few positive values for $a$ and $b$ and then choosing $I<a/b$, we see the inequality holds. Of course trying few values doesn't mean the inequality holds for all values but I hope you get my point, so I'm curious about cases where it fails..

Comment: yes, I see the point. I made some obvious mistake. Will get back to it

Comment: As Log is a monotonic function in the Reals, therefore, from i<=a/b follows that Log[i]<= Log[] or -Log[i]>-Log[a/b]

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you for confirming.